# OCaml function name collison between two modules

Tags: ocaml

The following codes shows b is overided by A.b after opening A. However, A.b and B.b have difference signatures, A.b takes an integer parameter while B.b takes a float parameter. They should not overide each other, is it right?

```
# module A=struct  let b x = x*10 end;;
module A : sig val b : int -> int end
# module B=struct let b x =x*. 3.14159 end ;;
module B : sig val b : float -> float end
# open B;;
# open A;;
# b 10;;
- : int = 100
# b 10.;;
Error: This expression has type float but an expression was expected of type
         int
#
```

Comment: what makes you think it is not "right"?

Answer (score 3):

OCaml does not have the kind of overloading you're talking about. Every name refers to just one object. Types are not considered when deciding the meaning of a name.

You can refer to `B.b` by its full name:

```
# B.b 10.;;
- : float = 31.4159
```

It's also good to avoid opening modules, except for a few carefully chosen ones.

Comment: Right, I was trying to avoid complexities.

Answer (score 3):

In OCaml, if you open two modules with same names inside, you are generating a name conflict (a silent one) and the last opened or defined is gonna shadow the others. So you should refer to full name (including module and function) if both modules share an equal name (`B.b` or `A.b`).

If you want to define a shortcut to a function inside a module you can always define it as `let a_b = A.b`.